# Python Multiprocessing map_async() skipping worker proccess in pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pool

I am running Python 3.5.2, and it seems that my pool is not calling the target function for some worker jobs. I currently have a list of length 630, where each element is a np.array. A pool of workers is then created for each element of this this using map_async(). As a some what condensed version of what is happening in my script, let us consider the following example code,

```py
def run(grid_point):
    index, geometry = grid_point # unpack tuple passed in 
    parent = os.getcwd()
    checkfile = "%s/CHECK/Check_GP%s.chk" % (parent, index) # file for each process for debugging purposes.
    setup.logging(checkfile, message='Calculation started!') # write calculation started in file for each process N.
    
    ''' Do some stuff with geometries via. interface to external code. '''   # Some other routines that do some calculation based on input

    if normal_termination:
        ''' write some output to some array with global memory sharing between processes ''' 
        # if calculation finished succesfully some output numbers (always non-zero) are written to a .npy array

    else: 
        ''' fill array for that process with NaN ''' # if calculation fails, those elements are NaN.


cpus = int((multiprocessing.cpu_count())/2) # 16 cpus here
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpus)
pool.map_async(run, [(k, v) for k, v in enumerate(list_geom)]) # list of molecular geometries to do stuff too in target function run. N.B. len(list_geom) = 630. 
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Here, if the calculation runs as expected for all 630 points, one would expect 630 *.chk files with the message 'Calculation started!' inside. In addition, since the numbers written to the output array are always non-zero (including if the external code's calculation fails - set to NaN), I would also expect this array to have no zero values.

Instead, what I see is that there are only 580 *.chk files present once my python script finishes running. Moreover, there are 50 elements in the output array that are zero (this array is initialised using np.zeros). This indicates, that 50 out of the 630 jobs submitted to the pool do not even start. In addition, in some other routines I have written that are called within this run() function, the programme will create a directory containing some output for each of the 630 jobs. Again of these 630 output directories that should be created, 50 are missing.

If anyone has any idea as to why map_aync() would appear to skip jobs in the pool, or perhaps what would lead to the target function run() not being called for a selection of 50 processes in the pool, I would be keen to hear your ideas! I am rather new to this kind of programming and am really stumped with this one. Thank you!

Comment: You aren't waiting for the work to complete. `map_async` returns an `AsyncResult` object and you have to wait on that somewhere before doing something that would terminate the pool. You may be better off just using `map`, which waits, instead.

Comment: But I am not doing anything to terminate the pool am I? All of the IO stuff is done inside the target function, so I do not understand why this would cause me to be missing 50 .chk files? Unless since map_aync is not syncronised, some of my processes are accessing shared memory at the same time, causing the call to target func to fail?

Comment: @tdelaney I haven't looked at this problem but I can tell you that doing a `pool.close()` followed by a `pool.join()` will wait for all outstanding tasks that have been submitted to complete. So waiting on the `AsyncResult` that was created by `map_async` is not strictly necessary except to get returned values or errors.

Comment: You might wish to code the *error_callback* argument to the `map_async` call to see if an exception is being thrown (there might actually be 50 individual ones, but using this method you would only see one). If there is an exception, consider using method `imap` with a suitable *chunksize* argument for efficiency (for example: `len(iterable) // (4 * pool_size)` or specifically: `chunksize, remainder = divmod(630, 4 * cpus); if remainder: chunksize += 1`) and you can then iterate individual results, which could throw exceptions.

Comment: @Booboo - The question was editted to show the close after I made the comment.

Comment: There may be exceptions raised in the worker. You should wait on the AsyncResult object, check its `successful` method and potentially call its `get` method to see if this happened.

Comment: @tdelaney Oh, Thanks.